# Receiving "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'" errors.

Tags: c#, asp.net

My first time posting here. Have searched quite a bit here looking for a solution, but so far nothing.

Have a website running on a shared hosted environment. Site has been going down randomly, and I can't figure out why. Have been in contact with hosting company, and they don't have any specifics.

When site goes down, it is either a 500 error, or 503. If 500, I can login and recycle the app pool and that will bring the site back up. If 503, the host has to reset server.

Site is asp.net 4.0. Pages in site read and write to sql server.

I don't know where to look for solution. Below are a couple of the error messages that are generated when site goes down.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

---

### Cookies: System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+KeysCollection Session: System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+KeysCollection Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Source: App_Web_vezkqdka Method: Void Page_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs) Stack Trace: at Controls_RunnerStats2016.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

and another one...

Cookies: System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+KeysCollection Session: System.Collections.Specialized.NameObjectCollectionBase+KeysCollection Message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown. Source: App_Code Method: System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod CreateDynamicCompareMethod(srvef.SortProperty[]) Stack Trace: at srvef.DynamicComparer`1.CreateDynamicCompareMethod(SortProperty[] sortProperties) at srvef.DynamicComparer`1.Initialize(SortProperty[] sortProperties) at customers_CreateAccount.CreateStatesDropdownList() at customers_CreateAccount.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: My guess is there are very large objects in Session storage or other static variables.  Basically, a memory leak.

Comment: Hi Mason...that's part of the issue. No idea what section of code may be causing issue. In the error emails I have sent to me when the site goes down, this happens with random pages.

Comment: If you look at the stack traces you provided, it mentions several bits of your code. I would start looking there. OOM exceptions aren't always easy to figure out, but you should read up on what causes them so you can try to find the issue. Perhaps an infinite loop, not disposing of resources properly, loading a bunch of things into memory and not removing them etc. Asking everyone on Stack Overflow to fix it for you isn't going to be very productive because we don't have access to your source code.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback Mason. I hope I didn't come off as asking everyone to fix this. I have been trying for a few weeks to read through and look stuff up and see what may be happening, but I have not been able to get there. Thus I decided to post here to see if anyone had advice as to how to track this down.

I tired running JustTrace (Telerik performance profiling software) this morning to see if that revealed clues.

I'll keep looking.

Comment: Looks to me like you might be storing waaay too much in a collection somewhere, perhaps one being stored in Application scope and thus growing over time and causing the 50x errors you are experiencing. Hard to be more speculative/specific without seeing at least some source.

Comment: The second instance of the crash dump suggests that it may be occurring somewhere within a sorting routine with a custom comparer defined - if that rings a bell on where it could be occurring that might suggest the collection that is causing the problem. Sure looks in a very general way like a collection is growing boundlessly and eventually seizing memory like crazy.